# Evaluating particular solution

Tags: recurrence-relations, signal-processing

I'm trying to find the solution to the following difference equation:

$$y[n] - \frac{1}{4} y[n-1] - \frac{1}{8} y[n-2] =3x[n] $$

with $x[n]=(\frac{1}{2})^nu[n]$  where $u[n]$ is a step signal defined as :

$$ u[n]= 1 \forall n\ge 0$$
$$= 0 \forall n<0 $$

but somehow my solution does not match the given solution.

The complementary solution or homogeneous solution is : $k_1(\frac{1}{2})^n+k_2 (\frac{-1}{4})^n]u[n]$

And after that I take the particular solution of the form $$y_p[n]=kn(\frac{1}{2})^nu[n]$$ since the input is of the same form as the roots of the characteristic equation.

and get k as equal to 2.

and evaluate the coefficients of complementary solution as
$$y[n]=\frac{8}{3} (\frac{1}{2})^n u[n]+\frac{1}{3} (\frac{-1}{4})^n u[n]+2n (\frac{1}{2})^n u[n]$$

but the solution given is $$\frac{1}{3} (\frac{1}{4})^n u[n] + 4(n+1)(\frac{1}{2})^{(n+1)} u[n+1] + \frac{2}{3} (\frac{1}{2})^n u[n]$$

I don't where the anomaly in my evaluation is? Or is the given solution wrong?
I'm new to the concept of difference equations.

I wish to solve this difference equation without using z transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resolution method not based on the $z$ transform.

Making $y_1(k) = y(k), y_2(k) = y_1(k+1)$ and $Y = (y_1, y_2)^{\dagger}$ we have

$$
Y_{k+1}= M Y_k + B x_k
$$

considering now $M = T\Lambda T^{-1}$ we have

$$
T^{-1}Y_{k+1}=\Lambda T^{-1} Y_k + T^{-1}B x_k
$$

making now $Z_k = T^{-1} Y_k,\ \ \ V = T^{-1}B $ we follow with

$$
Z_{k+1} = \Lambda Z_k + V x_k
$$

the homogeneous solution is direct

$$
Z_k^h = \Lambda^k C_0
$$

now assuming a particular solution $Z_k^p = \Lambda^k C_k$ and substituting into the complete recurrence

$$
\Lambda^{k+1}C_{k+1} = \Lambda^{k+1}C_k+V x_k
$$

gives the recurrence

$$
C_{k+1}-C_k = \Lambda^{-k-1}V x_k
$$

then

$$
C_k = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\Lambda^{-j-1}V x_j
$$

and finally

$$
Z_k=Z_k^h + Z_k^p = \Lambda^k C_0+\Lambda^k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\Lambda^{-j-1}V x_j
$$

hence

$$
Y_k = T Z_k
$$

NOTE

$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right),\ \ T = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & -4 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\ \ \Lambda = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{1}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right),\ \ B = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\ \ V = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{2}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{3} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$